# Cost of accessing data member through pointer

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, x86

I was curious to see what the cost is of accessing a data member through a pointer compared with not through a pointer, so came up with this test:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X{
    int a;
};

int main(){

    X* xheap = new X();
    std::cin >> xheap->a;
    volatile int x = xheap->a;

    X xstack;
    std::cin >> xstack.a;
    volatile int y = xstack.a;
}
```

the generated x86 is:

```
int main(){
 push        rbx  
 sub         rsp,20h  

    X* xheap = new X();
 mov         ecx,4  
 call        qword ptr [__imp_operator new (013FCD3158h)]  
 mov         rbx,rax  
 test        rax,rax  
 je          main+1Fh (013FCD125Fh)  
 xor         eax,eax  
 mov         dword ptr [rbx],eax  
 jmp         main+21h (013FCD1261h)  
 xor         ebx,ebx  
    std::cin >> xheap->a;
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cin (013FCD3060h)]  
 mov         rdx,rbx  
 call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator>> (013FCD3070h)]  
    volatile int x = xheap->a;
 mov         eax,dword ptr [rbx]  

    X xstack;
    std::cin >> xstack.a;
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cin (013FCD3060h)]  
 mov         dword ptr [x],eax  
 lea         rdx,[xstack]  
 call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator>> (013FCD3070h)]  
    volatile int y = xstack.a;
 mov         eax,dword ptr [xstack]  
 mov         dword ptr [x],eax
```

It looks like the non-pointer access takes two instructions, compared to oneinstruction for the access through a pointer. Could somebody please tell me why this is and which would take fewer CPU cycles to retrieve?

I am trying to understand if pointers do incur more CPU instructions/cycles when accessing data members through them as opposed to non-pointer-access.

Comment: Short answer, very very tiny.

Comment: Using pointers can lead to indirection, which can be slower. It can also be faster since some things are natural for pointers (like accessing something from a basepointer + offset). In fact, it all depends on *how* you are using the pointers, and there's no one simple answer.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like code I'd expect to see from compiling with optimization turned off.

Comment: @JerryCoffin -O2 enabled on MSVC 11.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg accessing the data member of an object through a pointer?

Comment: @user997112 As it's indirect access it should in theory be slow, but in practice the compiler will probably generate pretty optimized code even when no special optimizations enabled. Oh and remember that on many CISC platforms (like the x86 and its x86_64 child) instructions are not fixed time, even though some code have fewer instructions in assembler doesn't mean the code will be faster.

Comment: In general, a pointer dereference is 2 memory accesses while something like xstack.a is one memory reference.  Because of your tiny example, the optimizer was able to remove some memory references.  Each memory reference is usually a couple of dozen CPU cycles (assuming not cached).

Answer (score 1):

That's a terrible test.

The complete assignment to `x` is this:

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [rbx]  
mov         dword ptr [x],eax
```

(the compiler is allowed to re-order the instructions somewhat, and has).

The assignment to `y` (which the compiler has given the same address as `x`) is

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [xstack]  
mov         dword ptr [x],eax
```

which is almost the same (read memory pointed to by register, write to the stack).

The first one would be more complicated except that the compiler kept `xheap` in register `rbx` after the call to `new`, so it doesn't need to re-load it.

In either case I would be more worried about whether any of those accesses misses the L1 or L2 caches than about the precise instructions. (The processor doesn't even directly execute those instructions, they get converted internally to a different instruction set, and it may execute them in a different order.)

Accessing via a pointer instead of directly accessing from the stack costs you one extra indirection in the worst case (fetching the pointer). This is almost always irrelevant in itself; you need to look at your whole algorithm and how it works with the processor's caches and branch prediction logic.

Comment: I do appreciate the advice, but I know about micro-ops, branching and caching. I was just trying to understand the difference accessing through a pointer and not. Would you be able to provide a better test which demonstrates the difference in x86?